# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException [Dijkstra]

Tags: java, pointers, netbeans, null, dijkstra

[Dijkstra Algorithm]

**Hello everybody,**
I am trying to develop my dijkstra algorithm and I'm having trouble because in line 132/133 it shows me the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY65M.png)

Can someone help me solve this question, thanks!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sasf9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xATEL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQito.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH3vx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvhyj.png)

Comment: Please don't use images in your question. Put the code and error messages into your question as text.

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510